# What debating tactic does the monk Nagasena use against King Milinda?

Tags: buddhism, debate

<sub>Source: p 36, Chapter 4, *Philosophy ; A Very Short Introduction* (2002) by Edward Craig.

Chapter 4 here summarises [*Milindapañha, the Questions of
King Milinda*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milinda_Panha) the entirety of which I have not read.</sub>

> The king [Milinda], who is evidently experienced in this kind of discussion (and
>   also has considerable prior knowledge of Buddhism), doesn’t despair
>   but sets out to get to the bottom of it. Realizing that Nagasena wasn’t
>   just speaking of himself, but intended the point he was making
>   (whatever it may have been) to apply equally to everyone, he starts
>   drawing what he takes to be absurd consequences from the monk’s
>   view. If it is true, then nobody ever does anything, right or wrong,
>   nobody ever achieves anything, suffers anything. There is no such thing
>   as a murder, for there is no person who dies. And then a little joke about
>   Nagasena’s status: there was no one who taught him, and no one who
>   ordained him. **The tactic is common in debates of all kinds**: here are a
>   number of things which we all unhesitatingly take to be true; is
>   Nagasena really saying that they are all false? Or is he going to tell us
>   that his view, if properly understood, doesn’t have that consequence?
>   Nagasena never takes that challenge up directly. By the end of the
>   chapter he has given a hint, from which we can reconstruct what he
>   might have said had he done so. But for the moment the king continues,
>   falling into question-and-answer style reminiscent of many of Plato’s
>   dialogues.

To what debating tactic does the bolded refer? I am inexperienced in debating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "tactic" is just the logical rule of reductio ad absurdum. The idea is that you show someone their thesis is false because it generates contradictions. You say p, and I show you if p, then q, so q. However, we have good reason to believe not q. Contradiction. Therefore, not p.

Comment: Note though that it's the king who is using the technique against the monk rather than vice versa